# How do I get a custom Rake task to run in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rake

*I want to get a custom Rake task to run in my Sinatra app but I keep getting `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'greet'`.

Here's the custom Rake task (`greet.rake`) for testing purpose:

```
task :greet do
  puts "Hello!"
end
```

I've put the `greet.rake` in `./lib/tasks` (Rails). I'm guessing Rake can't find the correct directory for the file.

How do I get a custom Rake task to run in Sinatra?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Sinatra 1.4.4.

#### UPDATE

The Rakefile now looks like this:

```
require "./app"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
require "./lib/tasks"
```

When using:

```
rake greet
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- ./lib/tasks
/Users/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-        4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/Users/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-    4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/Users/*/Dropbox/Development/Sinatra/sinatra-mp-experiment/Rakefile:3:in `<top    (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a `Rakefile` at your Sinatra app's top directory, require the file that contains this task you want to use and you should be good to go.

Edit:

A simple solution is changing your `Rakefile` to:

```
require "./app"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}
```

Now any `.rake` file under `lib/tasks` will be loaded.

Comment: I doesn't seem to be working. I've updated the original question.

Comment: Isn't lib/tasks a folder? why are you requiring a folder instead of a file?

Comment: I've also tried ./lib/tasks/greet.rake. I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Note, if you want to get tasks/ subdirectories as well, use the glob pattern `lib/tasks/**/*.rake`